# Unable to execute root commands inside an openvpn script

Tags: shell-script, openvpn, freebsd, chroot

I'm using the openvpn option client-connect to run a script when a client connects.

The script works fine when I use simple commands but when I add commands that need root privileges it doesn't work and clients can't connect to the VPN server.

For example here are some commands I try to execute:

`bgpctl reload` 
and

`route add -net $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip/30 -interface $dev -static`.

The commands are tested and work correctly. I'm using freeBSD.

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Thank you!

**Update**

Actually there was no privileges issue. 
The script could not execute the commands `bgpctl`and `route` because it couldn't recognize them.

I could fix the problem by specifying the full path to the commands:

`/usr/local/sbin/bgpctl reload`

`/sbin/route add -net $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip/30 -interface $dev -static`

Now it works.

Thanks roaima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--client-connect` script is run as the non-privileged OpenVPN user specified by the `--user` parameter.

You can verify this by adding these lines to the top of your `--client-connect` file and reviewing the output written to `/tmp/ov.log` after a successful connection

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >>/tmp/ov.log 2>&1
chmod 666 /tmp/ov.log 2>/dev/null
echo
date
id
echo "PATH=$PATH"

# Payload
bgpctl reload
route add -net "$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip/30" -interface "$dev" -static

# All done
true
```

On my system, using the `--user nobody` and `--group nogroup` directives I get this output:

```
Tue Jun  9 15:00:45 BST 2015
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
...
```

Since you get these as the `root` user and `wheel` group you are presumably not using the `--user` or `--group` directive.

It's also important to verify that the `PATH` contains the necessary directories for the commands you want to execute.

Comment: This is the output of the id command executed from the client-connect script `uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel)`. It seems to be the root user.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Actually I didn't get your idea. Just one information, OpenVPN is run as root.

Comment: @HaTiMuX it's necessary to start OpenVPN as root but generally recommended to downgrade its privileges as soon as possible. Please update your Question to provide an example of a command that fails, and (if appropriate) the output.

Comment: I think the problem is with all root commands. Anyway here are the commands I try to execute: `bgpctl reload` and `route add -net $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip/30 -interface $dev -static`. The commands are tested and work correctly.

Comment: Please [update your question](http://superuser.com/posts/925576/edit) with this information. Otherwise it can get lost in the comments.

Comment: I updated the question. Check it now.

Comment: @HaTiMuX Please review my updated answer, with particular relevance to the script. Does your `PATH` include the directories that include your `bgpctl` and `route` commands?

Comment: Ok I'm going to check.

Comment: Here is the output: `uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel)
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
/scripts/connect.sh: bgpctl: not found
/scripts/connect.sh: route: not found` So it seems the path to the commands are not found

Comment: So the problem was with the command path. Thank you very much. I'm gonna update the question and explain the solution later.